# .php vs .html - Why not always use .php?

Tags: php, html, file

.html files can translate html and css code. But .php files can do all that an html file can do plus use php. Are there any advantages in using html files over php files, especially in development of a responsive website?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Semantic:**

By using `*.html/*.htm` the reader immediately know, it is just plain `HTML`

**Performance*:**

- Every `html` file, that is been requested, is sended by the webserver immediately to the browser.
- For every `php` file, the webserver first starts the `PHP interpreter`, which is processing the file. After the file is processed, the output is send to the browser.

This means: `html` takes less cpu power/memory on your webserver. However you will never realy notice it, if you are not serving thousands of requests per second.

<sub>* not as much relavant as it's used to be, due to new caching technologies.</sub>

Comment: So if I intend on my multipage website to have a small audience, php is the way to go?

Comment: Use php extension if you write php code. If you only write html, use the html extension.

Answer (score 0):

Php is a Hypertext Processor that work's on server side. It generate content and send it to a browser which reads the content sent by php. Once it is in the client window, the page is fixed. That's why we use JavaScript on client side so the page can work on its own. It is the server that deal with the php file not the browser. You browser only reads markup language like html.